# Drawing a mathematical envelope with turtle graphics

Tags: python, beginner, turtle-graphics

I started coding a week ago. I played a bit with the turtle module and I am looking for ways to improve my code. Please feel free to share improvements.

Here is the shape it creates:

[image: star]

```py
#I created a mathematical envelope by connecting points laying on straight lines forming with the x-axis angles of 60, 90, 120, 180... deegrees

import turtle as t
import math

t.speed(0)
t.bgcolor("black")
t.pencolor("deepskyblue")


def star1(start, end, step, x_direction1, y_direction1, x_direction2):  #goes from the x-axis to a 60° straight line (slope = +- 3/sqrt(3))
    for i in range(start, end, step):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x_direction2 * (255 - 5.1 * i), 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.goto(x_direction1*255/100*(i+1), y_direction1* 3/math.sqrt(3)*255/100 * (i+1))


def star2 (start, end, step, x_direction1, y_direction1, x_direction2, y_direction2): #from 60° straight line to the simmetric in respect to the y-axis
    for i in range (start, end, step):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x_direction1*(127.5-255/100*i),y_direction1*3/math.sqrt(3)*(127.5-255/100*i))
        t.pendown()
        t.goto(x_direction2*255/100* (i+1), y_direction2 * 3/math.sqrt(3)*255/100*(i+1))


def refine (x_direction, y_direction):   #closing the inner spaces
    t.goto(x_direction * 127.5, y_direction * 3/math.sqrt(3) * 127.5)


def whole_star():      #star with spaces. The start, end and step indexes aren't all the same just for a smoother drawing animation
    star1(0, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    star2(0, 50, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1)
    star1(49, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1)
    star1(0, 50, 1, -1, -1, -1)
    star2(0, 50, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1)
    star1(49, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1)


def final_star():      #refined star
    whole_star()
    t.penup()
    t.goto(255, 0)
    t.pendown()
    t.goto(-255, 0)
    t.penup()
    refine(-1, 1)
    t.pendown()
    refine(1, -1)
    t.penup()
    refine(1, 1)
    t.pendown()
    refine(-1, -1)


final_star()
t.hideturtle()
t.done()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's good that you got this working (especially since you only started a week ago). It's also unsurprising that you're using turtle, which is geared toward beginner graphics.

As you've already seen, it takes some time for the drawing to render. A more scalable approach is to use Numpy and Matplotlib, which offers several advantages:

- It's much faster (especially if you write the curve construction to be vectorised)
- It does polar coordinate systems for you, so that your own curve definitions are much simpler
- It can draw axes, etc.
- It's more suitable for "mathematical objects" (however you interpret that)

An implementation could look like:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


def star(points: int, resolution: int) -> np.ndarray:
    # four-dimensional array: points, resolution, line start/end, angle/radius
    coords = np.empty((points, resolution, 2, 2))

    # all angles in radians
    circle = 2*np.pi
    theta = circle / points   # point angle increment

    # indexer to convert vectors to (n, 1)
    d2 = (slice(None), np.newaxis)

    # start ray angles, including 0, excluding full rotation
    coords[..., 0, 0] = np.arange(
        0, circle - 0.5*theta, theta,
    )[d2]

    # end ray angles, excluding 0, including full rotation
    coords[..., 1, 0] = np.arange(  # end ray angles
        theta, circle + 0.5*theta, theta,
    )[d2]

    # start line radii, starting at the ray centre, excluding the circumference
    coords[..., 0, 1] = np.arange(
        0, 1, 1/resolution,
    )

    # end line radii, starting at the ray circumference, excluding the centre
    coords[..., 1, 1] = np.arange(
        1, 0, -1/resolution,
    )

    # all coords, line start/end, angle/radius
    return coords.reshape((-1, 2, 2))


def plot(coords: np.ndarray) -> plt.Figure:
    plt.style.use('dark_background')
    sky_blue = '#00a0da'
    lines = LineCollection(coords, colors=sky_blue, alpha=0.2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
    ax.add_collection(lines)
    return fig


def demo() -> None:
    coords = star(points=6, resolution=50)
    plot(coords)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

[image: six points]

It's also effectively "instant" to generate a much larger diagram, shown here with 16 points and a quite-excessive resolution of 300 line segments per point:

[image: 16 points]

To get fancier, you can auto-estimate an appropriate line alpha, and auto-assign tick frequency:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

# ...

def plot(coords: np.ndarray, points: int, resolution: int) -> plt.Figure:
    plt.style.use('dark_background')

    # More resolution means we need more transparent lines
    alpha_estimate = min(1., 10/resolution)
    sky_blue = '#00a0da'
    lines = LineCollection(coords, colors=sky_blue, alpha=alpha_estimate)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
    ax.add_collection(lines)

    # Align the theta axis ticks to evenly spaced points
    circle = 2*np.pi
    theta = circle / points
    locator = FixedLocator(
        locs=np.arange(0, circle - 0.5*theta, theta),
        nbins=12,  # limit tick count
    )
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

    return fig


def demo() -> None:
    points = 6
    resolution = 100
    coords = star(points=points, resolution=resolution)
    plot(coords, points=points, resolution=resolution)
    plt.show()
```

[image: autoticks]

> I was wondering if you could also animate it like in turtle.

Yes; matplotlib has animation support:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator


def star(points: int, resolution: int) -> np.ndarray:
    # four-dimensional array: points, resolution, line start/end, angle/radius
    coords = np.empty((points, resolution, 2, 2))

    # all angles in radians
    circle = 2*np.pi
    theta = circle / points   # point angle increment

    # indexer to convert vectors to (n, 1)
    d2 = (slice(None), np.newaxis)

    # start ray angles, including 0, excluding full rotation
    coords[..., 0, 0] = np.arange(
        0, circle - 0.5*theta, theta,
    )[d2]

    # end ray angles, excluding 0, including full rotation
    coords[..., 1, 0] = np.arange(
        theta, circle + 0.5*theta, theta,
    )[d2]

    # start line radii, starting at the ray centre, excluding the circumference
    coords[..., 0, 1] = np.arange(0, 1, 1/resolution)

    # end line radii, starting at the ray circumference, excluding the centre
    coords[..., 1, 1] = np.arange(1, 0, -1/resolution)

    return coords


def make_artists(points: int, resolution: int) -> tuple[
    plt.Figure, plt.PolarAxes, LineCollection,
]:
    plt.style.use('dark_background')

    # More resolution means we need more transparent lines
    alpha_estimate = min(1., 20/resolution)
    sky_blue = '#0ae'
    lines = LineCollection([], colors=sky_blue, alpha=alpha_estimate)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
    ax.add_collection(lines)

    # Align the theta axis ticks to evenly spaced points
    circle = 2*np.pi
    theta = circle / points
    locator = FixedLocator(
        locs=np.arange(0, circle - 0.5*theta, theta),
        nbins=12,  # limit tick count
    )
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

    return fig, ax, lines


def make_plot(coords: np.ndarray, lines: LineCollection) -> None:
    lines.set_segments(coords.reshape((-1, 2, 2)))


def animate(
    frame: int, coords: np.ndarray, lines: LineCollection,
) -> tuple[plt.Artist, ...]:
    subarray = coords[:, :frame, ...]
    lines.set_segments(subarray.reshape((-1, 2, 2)))
    return lines,


def make_animation(
    fig: plt.Figure, coords: np.ndarray, lines: LineCollection,
    resolution: int, duration: float = 5,
) -> FuncAnimation:
    n_frames = resolution
    frame_ms = 1e3 * duration / n_frames
    return FuncAnimation(
        fig=fig, func=animate, fargs=(coords, lines),
        frames=n_frames, interval=frame_ms, repeat=False,
    )


def demo() -> None:
    points = 6
    resolution = 100
    coords = star(points=points, resolution=resolution)
    fig, ax, lines = make_artists(points=points, resolution=resolution)

    # make_plot(coords=coords, lines=lines)
    anim = make_animation(
        fig=fig, coords=coords, lines=lines, resolution=resolution,
    )
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

It works, though I can't be bothered to make a screen recording.

Comment: First, thank you for all the suggestions. I am really impressed: yours looks way cleaner. I honestly can't understand a single line of your code since i have never tried matplotlib, but I will for sure! I was wondering if you could also animate it like in turtle.

Comment: @Lorenzo yes - see edit

Answer (score 7):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- Overall code layout is good
- You did a good job partitioning code into functions
- You leveraged code written by others with the imports
- Used meaningful names for functions

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Documentation

Add comments at the top of the file to state the purpose of the code.  For example:

```
'''
I created a mathematical envelope by connecting points laying
on straight lines forming with the x-axis angles of 
60, 90, 120, 180... degrees
'''
```

Refer to the  [PEP 8 Style Guide for Comments](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#comments) and Docstrings for more information.

### Layout

I recommend moving the functions to the top, after the `import` statements.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few style issues.

It identifies long lines of code and missing function docstrings.
Kill two birds with one stone and place those end-of-line comments into
docstrings:

```
   def whole_star():
       '''
       star with spaces. The start, end and step indexes
       aren't all the same just for a smoother drawing animation
       '''
```

It would be helpful to users of your code to know what value ranges are
valid for your function inputs.  For example, for the `refine` function,
add the expected ranges for `x_direction`, etc, to the docstring.
You could even add code to check for valid input values.

### Typos

`deegrees` should be `degrees`.

`simmetric` should be `symmetric`